# Как использовать строковые данные в Enum Flag

Tags: c#

Как использовать `string` параметры в перечислении? Примерно вот так

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    First = "Привет",
    Second = "Здрасти"
}
```

Comment: Enum.GetName(Type MyEnumType,  object enumVariable)

Comment: Он не пускает мне строковые поля занести. Тока int

Comment: @Radzhab в .net вообще нельзя использовать строки в качестве значений. underlying type всегда должен быть int.

Comment: [Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    Привет,
    Здрасти
}

Console.Write(Enum.GetName(typeof(DaysOfWeek), DaysOfWeek.Привет)); //на правах бреда, но работать будет

Comment: В связи с используемым вами атрибутом Flags возникает вопрос: что вы желаете получить, если написать `var day = DaysOfWeek.First | DaysOfWeek.Second;` ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Используя атрибут и метод расширения с возвращением соответствующего значения трибута.
2. Используя метод расширения и простой `Switch` по элементам `Enum`.

[Оба варианта можно посмотреть в первых двух ответах](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479410/enum-tostring-with-user-friendly-strings)

Comment: Кстати, если вас не инетресует локализация, можно использовать вариант в  комментарии @Konst, т.е. просто назвать значения переменных по русски.

Comment: Также хочу добавить, что первый вариант короче и локаничнее, но второй будет работать быстрее, т.к. не использует методы отражения.

Answer (score 1):

В перечисления помеченных атрибутом `System.FlagsAttribute` - никак.

`System.FlagsAttribute` указывает на что перечисление будет перечислением битовых флагов, что в свою очередь позволит выполнять битовые операции `AND`, `OR`, `NOT` и `XOR`.

И вообще enum - это стековый тип, и не может иметь значения ссылочных типов.

Comment: Ну а как сделать стринговый hashset скажем так в Enum?

Comment: @Radzhab, что Вы имеете ввиду опишите детальней.. Вы видили/челали что-подобное на CLI-языке?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем ясно, что именно вам нужно. Вероятно, описание для каждого значения перечисления. Для этого можно навесить атрибут на каждое значение:

```
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    [Description("Привет")]
    First,

    [Description("Здрасти")]
    Second
}
```

Для удобного получения этих описаний напишем метод расширения:

```
static class EnumExtensions
{
    static public string Description(this DaysOfWeek value)
    {
        var attribute = value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .First() as DescriptionAttribute;

        return attribute.Description;
    }
}
```

Использовать можно так:

```
var day = DaysOfWeek.First;
Console.WriteLine(day.Description()); // выводит Привет
```

Не забудьте открыть пространства имён:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: `.First() as DescriptionAttribute;` - жесть. Других атрибутов не существует что ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я старался сделать как можно более короткий пример. Причём рабочий. Будут другие атрибуты - будет другой код.

Comment: А что, вариант `.FirstOrDefault(a => a is DescriptionAttribute) as DescriptionAttribute` сильно сложнее? Ну и `return attribute != null ? attribute.Description : value.ToString()` или даже `return attribute?.Description ?? value.ToString()`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Более того, есть же `System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions`. Правильно писать так: `type.GetField(name).GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ?? name`.

Comment: @Discord Это расширение появилось только в .NET 4.5. Неизвестно, какая версия у автора. Спору нет, это удобнее.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov .NET 4.5 уже три года. Приводить примеры для .NET 2.0 сейчас несколько неактуально.